# CSOM: Copying a document from one library to another - remote server returned 403 Forbidden error

Tags: c#, permissions, sharepoint-online, csom, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I am using the below code to copy the documents from one library to another but running into a remote server 403 Forbidden error on Line 'destContext.ExecuteQuery();' even though the service account is a site collection admin on the destination records library.

```
                            var absoluteUrl = new Uri(ctx.Url).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + bookLocation;
                            var srcUrl = absoluteUrl;
                            var destUrl = "https://xxx/sites/abcArchive";
                            var srcLibrary = "Documents";
                            var destLibrary = "Record Library";

                            ClientContext destContext = new ClientContext(destUrl);
                            ClientContext srcContext = new ClientContext(srcUrl);
                            Web srcWeb = srcContext.Web;
                            List srcList = srcWeb.Lists.GetByTitle(srcLibrary);         
                            Web destWeb = destContext.Web;
                            destContext.Load(destWeb);
                            **destContext.ExecuteQuery();**
                            try
                            {
                                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = srcContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(bookLocation);
                                srcContext.Load(file);
                                srcContext.ExecuteQuery();
                                string location = destWeb.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/') + "/" + destLibrary.Replace(" ", "") + "/" + file.Name;
                                FileInformation fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(srcContext, file.ServerRelativeUrl);
                                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(destContext, location, fileInfo.Stream, true);
                            }
```

I fail to understand what other permissions that need to be setup other than giving the site collection admin rights to the service account on the archive library. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Missing credentials to log in.
Add following code under `ClientContext`

```
var strPassword = "password";
SecureString secureString = new SecureString();
strPassword.ToList().ForEach(secureString.AppendChar);
destContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com", secureString);
srcContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com", secureString);
```

Comment: Thank you @RaytheonXie-MSFT for your response. This worked :) I was able to get past the 403 error but now running into  ' Cannot contact site at the specified URL example.com/sites/applications/abc/123456/Shared Documents/01 xyz Book . There is no Web named "/sites/applications/abc/123456/Shared Documents/01 xyz Book /_vti_bin/sites.asmx" error.  I believe my filepath is incorrect. Any ideas please? Appreciate your help.

Comment: This is the filepath that I am passing in -- /sites/applications/abc/123456/Shared Documents/01 xyz Book.